# Using If else in posgreSQL function - syntax error

Tags: sql, postgresql, function

I am trying to create a function that will execute different SQL based on provided input to the function (i.e. IF ELSE). I am trying something like below but keep getting a syntax error. Does anyone know what I am doing wrong? Any pointers will be greatly appreciated!

```
CREATE or replace FUNCTION sales_price(group_by text) 
RETURNS table(first_name text, price decimal)
AS $$

  IF group_by="x" THEN
    select first_name, price from table1;
  ELSIF group_by="y" THEN
    select first_name, price from table2;
  END IF;
$$ LANGUAGE SQL IMMUTABLE;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have several issues, but the biggest is `sql` rather than `plpgsql`:

```
CREATE or replace FUNCTION sales_price(group_by text) 
RETURNS table(first_name text, price decimal)
AS $$
BEGIN
  IF group_by = 'x' THEN
    return query select t1.first_name, t1.price from table1 t1;
  ELSIF group_by = 'y' THEN
    return query select t2.first_name, t2.price from table2 t2;
  END IF;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=b33c993f5bf7e0a7d209c3fa1eb13f9e) is a db<>fiddle.

I removed the `IMMUTABLE` because the function is not (well, I suppose you might know that the underlying tables never change).

Comment: Thank you for this! Super helpful to see where my mistakes were.

Comment: How do you do nested ifs in the return query? For example if I have another variable "joined_to" and based on that I want to union a table. Can I do something like

`IF group_by = 'x' THEN
    return query select t1.first_name, t1.price from table1 t1 IF joined_to="a" THEN UNION ALL SELECT * from table3; END IF;  `

Comment: @zeroanthem86: This function isn't IMMUTABLE, it does a table lookup. https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createfunction.html